# files not showing in iTunes w/ File Sharing

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-io, nsstring

I am attempting to write a `NSString` to a file, then view that file in iTunes. I have the `Application supports iTunes file sharing` key set to `YES` and I am able to see File Sharing in iTunes. A file never shows up though.

Here is how I'm writing the file:

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];

        NSString *fileName = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        fileName = [fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];
        fileName = [fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString* rootPath = paths[0];
        NSString *path = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        path = [path stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"txt"];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

        NSString *writeString = @"Hello world";

        NSError *error;
        BOOL ok = [writeString writeToURL:url atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:&error];

        if (!ok) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"File saved to: '%@'", path);
        }
```

This is the file location:

```
'/var/mobile/Applications/066FD6CD-0E5F-4701-9344-46258ABF0E97/Library/Wednesday_September_17_2014.txt'
```

And good ole iTunes:

[image]

Comment: you want `NSDocumentDirectory` not `NSLibraryDirectory `

Comment: -.- I need sleep. Add that as the answer and I'll accept. Thank ya sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want `NSDocumentDirectory` not `NSLibraryDirectory`

get some sleep sir! ;)